# How can I programmatically use several different (isolated) wallets?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, json-rpc, wallet.dat

I want to use several different wallets (as if one wallet = one account), and want to make sure the spending and receiving activities are exclusive to one wallet at a time.

- How can I interface with multiple wallets?  (through a program or script)
- How can I access multiple wallets at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean with "access multiple wallets at the same time"?

Comment: PS: are you sure the "accounts" feature isn't what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Currently bitcoind is designed to only run one wallet at a time.  You would have to run multiple daemons on different ports and connect to each separately.

That said, it looks like multiple wallet support is being [actively developed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2124) and will be available possibly in 0.9, based on this [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2220#issuecomment-14005170).

Comment: Is it there now ? I checked but didn't found any API call or related command-line argument.